# Webrtc and Asterisk security

Tags: webrtc, asterisk

We have an Asterisk server. And we want to create a mobile app with Jssip lib on Cordova. It uses WebRTC.
We will not give to the clients login data for peers, but we need a dynamical accounting. Like when he calls to us, the server will give him a login data for some peer.
So, how can we do something like this? And how can we differ users and hackers?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. As it currently stands this question is very broad, try doing some of the work yourself and ask a question if you have a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are alot of possible approach, but you have do it yourself(it not in client).

Simplest ways are :

1. register with known info like guest/guest and ask account via sip
   message
2. create http api, use it from javascript before start
   jssip.

However since you are gooing to give ANYONE credentials, i am afraid no way deals with DDoS attack or hackers.